# Invalid Syntax and I don't know why

Tags: python

I have this code in Python 3. I am a begginer so links to good sites will also be helpful. Anyway my goal is to find two duplicated numbers in a list and then find the number of elements between them. When I run my module it comes up as invalid syntax with no explanation. All it said was Invalid Syntax with nothing else. Any help is appreciated.

```
def pirate_list(thelist):
    duplicate = set()
    duplicate_add = duplicate.add
    f = []
    for i in thelist:
        if i in duplicate or duplicate_add(i):
            f.append(i)
            print (f)
            f.reverse()
            print(f)
            break
        else:
            f.append(i)
            print ("fail")
pirate_list([6,1,0,2,1,6])
def count_list(f):
    duplicate = set()
    duplicate_add = duplicate.add
    s = []
    for x in f:
        if x in duplicate or duplicate_add(x):
            s.append(x)
            print len(s)
            break
        else:
            s.append(x)
count_list(f)
```

Comment: How about you post the actual full error message?

Comment: "with no explanation"? It should have had an error message.

Comment: If this is your exact code, it's missing indentation on several lines, starting with line 2.

Answer (score 1):

If it is python2 code, then the only error I find is the undefined variable `f` in the last line.

If it is python3 code, then you must change `print len(s)` to `print(len(s))` as print is a function in python3 and not a separate statement keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The text under each `def` statement should be indented.

The last line refers to `countlist` which is not defined, and `f` which is defined inside a different function.

Comment: how would I define f in the function?

Comment: @smcavoy19 - This is fundamental stuff. I highly recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I was mistaken, I didn't notice `f` was the argument of the `count_list()` function. What is the last line of code intended to do, and is it intended to be inside or outside the `count_list()` function?

Comment: (I think I am answering this question) It is intended to find the duplicate again which should be in list f and then find the length of the new list s

Comment: list `f` doesn't exist, because the function `pirate_list()` is never called. And even if it had been called, it prints `f` but doesn't return it for use outside the `pirate_list()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `def` statements are to be indented. `countlist` should be `count_list`, on the last line as Jonathon Clede said.

Make it a practice to learn to understand error messages. They are vital to debugging your code. Even though there was no real error message this time, be sure to do it other times. `SyntaxError` by itself is usually caused by a pesky error like this indentation one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. It was a rookie mistake forgetting parentheses for the print len(s) and also bringing the f list outside the functions.

Comment: You are very welcome. If you found an answer to you question, you can accept it. Also, dont use the "Add an Answer" button for adding new information to a question, or to reply to an answer, because this way we people don't get notified about the change. Instead, you can comment, edit the answer, and ultimately mark the best one as accepted, so the question gets closed.